# In mongoDB, find all username containing a letter

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to find all usernames that contains one specific caracter ?

Something like this:

```
$collection->find(array("username" => 'a'));
```

=> and i get all caracters with the letter 'a'

Comment: Can you give the URL of the precise post please, i could not find it, thanks

Comment: Click on the 'How do I query mongodb with "like"?' text in the duplicate header at the top of your question.